# Show Div Between 9-5:30 Mon-Friday Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get a div to display between 9-5:30 Monday-Friday but cannot seem to get it to functioning properly. The div still displays. My code is below:

```
<script>// get current time
var d = new Date(), 
hours = d.getHours(),
mins = d.getMinutes();
day = d.getDay();   

// if day is mon-Fri and time is between 9am and 5:30pm
if(0 < dday < 6   
    && hours >= 9 
    && (hours < 17 || hours === 17 && mins <= 30)){

    $('.mydiv').show(); 
 };</script>

 <div class="mydiv">
<p>Put code here</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for starter..typo mistake in variable `dday` which rather should be `day`...

Comment: Also, I don't think `0 < dday < 6` has defined behavior.  It returns something like `!!6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide it as well when the test fails. And, since you're using a plain script block that gets executed immediately, you need to put this code after you've defined the `<div>` in HTML.

```
 if(0 < day < 6    // day here ???    
    && hours >= 9 
    && (hours < 17 || hours === 17 && mins <= 30)){

    $('.mydiv').show(); 
 } else {
    $('.mydiv').hide(); 
 }
```

Or, you could have it be hidden by default as

```
<div class="mydiv" style="display: none">
 <p>Put code here</p>
</div>
```

If you wouldn't like to reorder the script block then wrap it in a document.ready event handler as

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  // day logic here
});
```